# Extracting both text and images in their correct order from a pdf using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdfbox

I'm trying to parse a `pdf` document using `Apache PDFBox`. I've managed to extract text and images separately, but I'm wondering is it possible to extract both in their respective orders.

I haven't gone through the entire library, but I think it's possible to extract text and its positioning in the document. Is there a way to use this to know where to correctly insert an image?

Comment: Did you try the PrintTextLocations.java and the PrintImageLocations.java examples?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The PrintImageLocations doesn't work for my case, it prints 0.0,0.0 position for all found images.

Comment: Could you share that PDF? Also make sure you're using the latest version.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'm using the class from their latest release (`2.0.9`) found in `https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/2.0.9/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java`. Extra information, is that this class also prints sizes of the images, this one works fine.

Comment: The latest release is 2.0.17.